# How to show Date and weekday in one container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, containers

[image]

This question about how to customize table calendar and how to show day and date in one container.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
class CalendarScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
CalendarScreenState createState() {
return CalendarScreenState();
  }
}

class CalendarScreenState extends State<CalendarScreen> {
CalendarController controller = CalendarController();

 var arr = new List(7);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
arr[0] = "Mon";
arr[1] = "Tue";
arr[2] = "Wed";
arr[3] = "Thu";
arr[4] = "Fri";
arr[5] = "Sat";
arr[6] = "Sun";
return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
  child: TableCalendar(
    calendarController: controller,
    initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
    headerVisible: false,
    builders: CalendarBuilders(
      // week days
      dowWeekdayBuilder: (context, weekday) {
        return Container();
      },
      // dates
      dayBuilder: (context, date, events) {
        print(date.month);
        return Container(
          //  color: Colors.green,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6)),
              border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xffd6edff), width: 1)),

          child: Column(
            children: [
              _showDate(date),
              _showWeek(date),
            ],
          ),

          // ),
          // )),
        );
        //);
      },
    ),
  ),
 ));
 }

 Widget _showDate(DateTime date) {
 return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2), child: Text(arr[date.weekday - 1]));
 }

 Widget _showWeek(DateTime date) {
 return Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(2), child: Text('${date.day}'));
 }
 }
```